# Numerical Stability when Inverse CDF Sampling from Truncated Density

Tags: sampling, random-generation, cumulative-distribution-function, computational-statistics, numerics

Let $f(x)$ be the pdf of a random variable that we want to truncate to the interval $[a,b]$ and then sample from it. Let $F(x)$ denote the corresponding cdf. We can use inverse cdf sampling and generate a draw from the truncated version of $f(x)$ via

$u \sim Unif(0,1)$

$x \sim F^{-1}[u * (F(b) - F​(a)) + F​(a)]$

which is, however, numerically instable when, e.g., both $a$ and $b$ are very far in the right tail of $f(x)$, where the probability mass is numerically very close to zero. Is there a numerically more stable version of inverse cdf sampling for such cases?

Comment: If you can compute directly and exactly$$\int_a^x f(x)\text dx\big/\int_a^b f(x)\text dx$$and numerically invert this function, this would work.

Comment: It depends on the details.  There can be algorithmic issues as well as issues of numerical stability to resolve.  Some situations permit clever solutions.  Others succumb to brute force, such as using infinite-precision computer algebra systems.  If you have a particular family of distributions in mind, then it would be best to specify it.

Comment: Good points, thanks. In my case, the pdf is an inverse gamma density.